# How to sum the value of the columns which involves M and B in R

Tags: r

[image]

Note:i have tried various codes,but no luck
tried segregating M and B using grep.
some how i got the below hint but unable to solve it.

Hint:Find out the row index where you have 'M' or 'B', you can use grep  for that, then clean the values for all rows in this column, convert into numeric type and then using the row indices stored earlier do the necessary arithmetic operation.

How to sum the value of the columns which involves M and B

```
M-- million
B--Billion
$--dollars
```

Values in this are character type.

```
DF

Brand value Company_adv

$10B $100B 
$11B $200M 
$13B $400M 
$20B $600B 
$$0B $700B
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are M and B? Is this a homework problem you're asking us to do for you?

Comment: Hi,One min please,iam trying to attach the image of my doubt

Comment: I have attached the image of my doubt,as iam facing some issues while pasting the exact query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track; the hint you supplied basically tells you how to do it. Here is some example code to make it more concrete:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF <- read.table(text = "Brand_value Company_adv
$10B $100B 
$11B $200M 
$13B $400M 
$20B $600B 
$$0B $700B",
header = TRUE)

as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]",
                "",
                grep("B",
                     DF$Company_adv,
                     value = TRUE)))
```

Comment: one doubt,here digit is decimal digit,how can i do for that?

Comment: `[^[:digit:]\\.]` perhaps.